# Permission denied (publickey). when connecting to AWS sever

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services

i just spun up an AMI with amazon and I'm able to SSH in just fine using the key created by amazon. I've added a user to the system and set their password and when I try to log in i get "Permission denied (publickey)." when connecting to the server.

```
spoofy@shell:~$ ssh -v spoofy@honey-aws-west
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to honey-aws-west [50.1.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-      1ubuntu3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 2f:80:ab:9d:38:35:ae:eb:a2:bf:bc:20:1f:d9:89:62
debug1: Host 'honey-aws-west' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/spoofy/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Trying private key: /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/spoofy/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I know that normally its a permissions problem in this situation but I've checked those and they seem fine.. also given that i can ssh -i blah.pem in .. i'm guessing it may be a different issue?  here is the sshd_config

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd(8) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port 1337
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 768

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no
# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

UsePAM yes
```

the user is not a super user..but does have sudo access.

Comment: System administration questions belong on http://www.serverfault.com -- this is a programming Q&A site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you mean that you cannot log in to this new user using a password.

First you need to check that ssh_config allows users to log in using a password. Depending on your default setup it may not be a default option.

Also if your new user has superuser permissions, it may also be blocked from loggin in using a password.

UPDATE:

You need to set one or both of these to yes. I don't remember the second, so try the first one.

```
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Comment: just edited the post.. for some reason couldn't paste it as a comment

Comment: ChallengeResponseAuthentication no -> yes was the solution.. thanks

Comment: For me both are yes.. but still error

Answer (score 2):

I'm not clear if you are trying to log in with or without a password. If you are trying to log in with a new user account and no password, you need to add the public key for your user to the `.ssh` directory `authorized_keys` file.

If your user is named 'spoofy', go to

```
/home/spoofy/.ssh/
```

and here create a file called `authorized_keys` with your public key in it.

Then you should be able to log in with

```
$ ssh spoofy@ec2-#####.amazonaws.com
```

I have a longer writeup here.

http://thekeesh.com/2011/05/setting-up-user-accounts-password-authentication-and-ssh-keys-on-a-new-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
ssh-keygen -R <server_IP>
```

to delete the old keys stored on the workstation
also works with  instead of

then doing the same ssh again it worked:

```
ssh -v -i <your_pem_file> ubuntu@<server_IP>
```

on ubuntu instances the username is: ubuntu
on Amazon Linux AMI the username is: ec2-user

I didn't have to re-create the instance from an image.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to run `restorecon` in the system

```
restorecon -r /home/*/.ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

use super user or try command in root account.

example :

su ssh -v -i /path/key.pem username@IP_machine